# Offline available documents from network drive

Tags: networking, mount, filesystem, shared-folders

At my university im part of quite alot of network folders, is there any way that when i log into ubuntu (18.4.0.1), at set interval or by terminal command, i can download the current version of the network folder for offline usage, as i often have litle to no connection making reading PDF's etc. hard or impossible. Simply copying to another folder would be fine aswell, this can be done manually, and would then just be a question about automation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, use `rsync` for that, so you can keep copy updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rsync` to keep folders/files synchronized, so make local copy and keep it update. rsync is a command line tool, you can write simple shell script what sync everything you need or use a gui tool, for example: `grsync`

Setup `grsync` session and save it, then later add files to it if need something new.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grsync
```